# How to parse a p tag content with no class and no id using SimpleHTMLdom parser?

Tags: dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

this is the html part i want to parse in order to get the text inside the `<p>` :

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="divIdontNeed"> hi </div>
    <p> I WANT THIS TEXT </p> <====== this is what i want
    <p> i don't want this one </p>
</div>
```

What i did is a loop (because the html above is on multiple pages and i want all of them on an array `$allTexts`) :

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=container]')->find('p',0) as $text){

                    array_push($allTexts, $text->plaintext);
                }
```

When i do that, i got an error saying `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on array in /path/to/MyTextParser.php`

Thank you all

Comment: Do you have multiple divs with the class "container"?

Comment: What i mean by 'multiple' is : the web site i'm parsing contains pagination, all pages contain this same html part (with different contents but same structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because the first `find()` returns an array of elements, not just one.

You need to do the loop on the results of that first `find()`:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=container]') as $element)
{
   foreach ($element->find('p',0) as $text){
   array_push($allTexts, $text->plaintext);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Not to be pretentious, just add 'foreach' in the 3rd line my friend ;) thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should choose the nth element you want .

```
$divObj=$html->find('div.container', 0);

echo $divObj->find('p', 0)->plaintext; //you are choosing only first p tag

echo $divObj->find('p', 1)->plaintext; //you are choosing only second p tag
```

In case you need text from all the p elements of the div, you need to do foreach

**OR**

you can choose it as next sibling of `div` with class `divIdontNeed`

```
$divObj=$html->find('div.divIdontNeed', 0)->next_sibling();

echo $divObj->plaintext;
```